# Java linkedlist insterting node at first position

Tags: java, linked-list

How i can modify this code from inserting the node from second position to the first position?

```
static void insertAtMid(int x)
    {

        if (head == null)
            head = new Node(x);
        else {

            Node newNode = new Node(x);

            Node ptr = head;
            int len = 0;


            while (ptr != null) {
                len++;
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }


            int count = (len >=1)? 1 : 0;
            ptr = head;


            while (count-- > 1)
                ptr = ptr.next;


            newNode.next = ptr.next;
            ptr.next = newNode;
        }
    }

    static void display()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null)  
        {
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)  
    {  

        head = null;
        head = new Node(23);
        head.next = new Node(45);
        head.next.next = new Node(12);
        head.next.next.next = new Node(67);

        System.out.println("Linked list before "+
                           "insertion: ");
        display();

        int x = 55;
        insertAtMid(x);

        System.out.println("\nLinked list after"+
                           " insertion: ");
        display();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new node at the beginning of a linked list, all you have to do is create a new node and then set its `next` value to the current head:

```
Node newHead = new Node(x);
newHead.next = head;
```

At this point, the new head is `newHead`, which has been inserted at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a temporary variable and do something like:

```
newNode = newNode() //the node you want to insert
tmp = head //assuming that head is accessible
head = newNode
newNode.next = tmp
head = newNode
```